# Thymeleaf disappearing element with class

Tags: html, spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I'm trying to show global errors for a form using Thymeleaf + Spring Boot. The template code is quite simple:

```
<p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('global')}" th:errors="*{global}"></p>
```

and it works.

The problem is when I add an html class, the same element is never shown when global errors are present:

```
<p th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('global')}" th:errors="*{global}" class="invalid-feedback"></p>
```

Removing the class attribute makes it working again. Is it a Thymeleaf bug, or am I missing something?

Comment: did you already try to use th:class instead?

Comment: Yes - it disappears then too.

Comment: is it really disappeared (not in sources) or just not visible?

Comment: There is no resulting html markup.

Comment: what css is contained in `invalid-feedback`?

Comment: Simple bootstrap things - margin, width and color.